# Improving hashmap query performance when input query doesnt match the data

Tags: java, performance, hashmap

Consider this data stored in a hashmap:

| VIN last 4 | License plate | Details |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 |  | VehicleObject1 |
| 2222 | ABC123 | VehicleObject2 |
| 5678 | ABC123 | VehicleObject3 |
| 5678 | XYZ123 | VehicleObject4 |

```
class VehicleKey{
 String vin4;
 String lPlate;
  public VehicleKey(String vin4, String lPlate){
   this.vin4=vin4;
   this.lPlate=lPlate;
  }
}
```

```
HashMap<VehicleKey,Object> vehicleMap = new HashMap<>();
vehicleMap.put(new VehicleKey("1234",null),VehicleObject1);
vehicleMap.put(new VehicleKey("2222","ABC123"),VehicleObject2);
vehicleMap.put(new VehicleKey("5678","ABC123"),VehicleObject3);
vehicleMap.put(new VehicleKey("2222","XYZ123"),VehicleObject4);
```

```
Vehicle findVehicle(String vin4, String lPlate){
 Vehicle vehicle = vehicleMap.get(vin4,lPlate);
 if (vehicle==null)
  vehicle = vehicleMap.get(vin4,null)
 return vehicle;
}
```

| Input Query | Expected Return |
| --- | --- |
| `findVehicle("1234","Blah123")` | VehicleObject1 |
| `findVehicle("1234",null)` | VehicleObject1 |
| `findVehicle("2222","Blash123")` | null |
| `findVehicle("2222","ABC123")` | VehicleObject2 |
| `findVehicle("5678","ABC123")` | VehicleObject3 |
| `findVehicle("5678",null)` | null |

Is there a more efficient way to query the Hashmap so that if one of the fields in the key object is null, its treated as an Any Match?
Right now, I have to query twice to make it work. Is there a way to make this faster so that the hashmap is not queried twice?

Comment: What is `vehicleMap.get(vin4,lPlate)`? There is no such method in `HashMap`.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer yes and the solution is to read HashMap documentation or some tutorials.

HashMap is a map based on hashing of the keys. It supports O(1) get/put operations. [Keys must have consistent implementations of hashCode() and equals() for this to work.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()). So in your code key VehicleKey must overwrite hashCode/equals methods.

hashCode method example

```java
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = vin4 != null ? vin4.hashCode() : 0;
    result = 31 * result + (lPlate != null ? lPlate.hashCode() : 0);
    return result;
}
```

and more important one. Equals method:

```java
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;//check if points to same object instance
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;//if one of object is null or different class

    VehicleKey that = (VehicleKey) o;
    if (Objects.equals(vin4, that.vin4) && Objects.equals(lPlate, that.lPlate)) {
        return true;
    }
    if (Objects.equals(vin4, that.vin4) && lPlate == null || that.lPlate == null) {
        return true;
    }
    return Objects.equals(lPlate, that.lPlate) && vin4 == null || that.vin4 == null;
}
```

For sure that if's must can be simplify.